Plotly mapbox map in Spyder jupyter notebook
I have this code in order to draw a map with plotly mapbox.
latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=10)
longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=10)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LAT': latitudes,
    'LON': longitudes
})

fig_osm = ptl.graph_objects.Figure()
fig_osm.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map", 'zoom': zoom})
fig_osm.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig_osm.add_annotation(x=0.5,y=0.95,text=title,showarrow=False)
fig_osm.add_trace(ptl.graph_objects.Scattermapbox(name=city, showlegend=showlegend, lat=df['LAT'], lon=df['LON'], marker=dict(size=2, color='blue'), hovertemplate="Lat: %{lat:.2f}°<br>Lon: %{lon:.2f}°<extra></extra>"))
fig_osm.show()

I want to run it from the Spyder jupyter notebook interface, but it gives me the following error:

Javascript Error: Failed to initialize WebGL.

and the map does not show neither does the trace.
I am running it from Windows 10 in Spyder(Python 3.11)
